# Using R to move the end of a string to the start of another variable's string for some rows

Tags: r, string

I am cleaning data in R and some of the CSVs have an unfortunate error. Occasionally, the first letter of the `school` character variable has instead been added to the end of the `gender` variable (which is normally a single character, `m` or `f`). Examples:

```
mydata <- data.frame(
  gender = c('m', 'm  H', 'f', 'f  C'),
  school = c('Hills College', 'ills College', 'Christian College', 'hristian College')
)
```

How can I identify these mistakes and move the trailing letter in `gender` to its rightful place at the start of `school`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do:

```
transform(mydata, 
         gender = sub("\\s+\\w+\\s*", "", gender),
         school = paste0(sub("\\w\\s*","", gender), school))
  gender            school
1      m     Hills College
2      m     Hills College
3      f Christian College
4      f Christian College
```

In tidyverse, you could do:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>%
  separate(gender, c("gender","first_char"), fill = "right") %>%
  replace_na(list(first_char = ""))%>%
  unite(school,first_char, school,sep = "")

  gender            school
1      m     Hills College
2      m     Hills College
3      f Christian College
4      f Christian College
```

Answer (score 2):

It's may be a solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
mydata %>% 
  mutate(school = if_else(str_count(gender) == 1,
                          school,
                          str_c(str_sub(gender, start = -1),
                                school)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can try using `sub` for a base R option:

```
# concatenate last letter of gender to front of school, if gender has dangling letter
mydata$school <- ifelse(grepl(" \\w$", mydata$gender),
                        paste0(sub("^.*(\\w)$", "\\1", mydata$gender), mydata$school),
                        mydata$school)

# remove dangling letter from gender, if present
mydata$gender <- sub("\\s+\\w$", "", mydata$gender)
mydata

  gender            school
1      m                 2
2      m     Hills College
3      f                 1
4      f Christian College
```